# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS login problem (incorrect login)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, login

I have a dual-boot system of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I primarily use my ubuntu however. Umm I tried to install Octave 4.0 into the system and then it somehow crashed and upon restart of the computer, I just cannot get into the desktop environment again.

I try to put in my login details and the system just gets stuck there and fails to load any further (only with the ubuntu background screen) Nothing else seems to happen..

I've also tried the terminal login process -> <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and even there, I cannot seem to login; I put my details in and it says that I have "Incorrect login" details

I want to resolve this however I can ASAP.

Could someone kindly offer me help on this issue and how I could recover and get back working into ubuntu desktop again?
Would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the most common reasons for 'Incorrect login' in the CLI are (1) mistaking the fullname that is shown on the GUI login screen (`John Smith`) for the login name (`jsmith`) and (2) keyboard layout issues (especially if your password contains punctuation or other special characters)

Comment: I've managed to resolve the login. It was actually my error. I did the "mv .Xauthority .Xauthority && exit" and then Ctrl + Alt + F7.

i even restarted but now I manage to find myself into the "login loop" problem whenever I put in the details
How should I proceed further? Kindly guide me please. Cheers